# Android layout can not display in device

Tags: android, xml, layout

My **Android Studio** version is `1.5.1`

I have created an `XML` and it can show well in the AndroidStudio,
but when i run it in `genymotion` or my phone,it can not show the layout.

I am annoyed at this.I do not know what is wrong.

hope someone could help me.

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ts4A.jpg)

code:

SplashActivity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mEnterButton; 
    private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.enter_button:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        mEnterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter_button);
        mEnterButton.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);

    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.button_first).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SplashActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

avtivity_splash_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/splashBackground">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/splash_tv_text"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:id="@+id/text_splash"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/splash_click_to_inter"
        android:id="@+id/enter_button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.geekband.geekbandprojects">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `I am annoying` Yes, you are indeed. Because you posted your code as an image, rather than as text.

Comment: I'm sorry,I must post 2 class code ,2 xml code, 1 run results and 1 xml preview.So I think pic maybe more straightforward...

Comment: For the future, remember to paste the code, not images. Images are only good to show us what you want to achieve and what you get instead. But I could not take out a part of it, correct it and post it as an answer.

Comment: OK,and thank you for point out my mistakes

Comment: I have pasted the code.

Comment: Fantastic. Next step, accept the answer which solved your problem.

Comment: OK.Really thank @Andy the android,@TheGuy and you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need a **PersistableBundle** ?
make your **OnCreateMethod** like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //anything here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm considering that you haven't already set the `SplashActivity` as the startup `activity`.So add the following code(or change it) on `Manifest`:

```
<activity
           android:name=".Splash"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
```

And let us know your `MainActivity` code and of course your `Manifest` with the logcat.

I will updated my answer after that.

And of course, i think you should use `onClick` on Oncreate method.

Comment: Thank you for your help.I have uploaded MainActivity and Manifest. I change my code as @Andy the android  gived,and now it works well! Does use onClick on Oncreate method means this?: setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){@Override......});

Comment: Exactly, that's why i said you should post your logcat here and at least, i said,  `i think you should use onClick on Oncreate method.` let us know if this answer was usefull by accepting it as the best answer.goodluck

Comment: what's the difference when i use onClick  on class or onCreate method?

Comment: this is an another question, Please use `Ask Question`